# Firebase - Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myapplication.Message

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'd like to implement `RecyclerView`, along with Firebase to my app. I have a simple structure of the firebase:

[image]

The keys, under the Message node, are randomly generated by using `.push()` on reference. The values are just some dummy messages.

**Model**

```
data class Message (val message: String? = null)
```

**MainActivity**

```
private lateinit var mAdapter: MessageAdapter
...

myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Message")

//Set database query
val messages = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
    .setQuery(myRef, Message::class.java)
    .build()

mAdapter = MessageAdapter(messages)

//Read data
val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.messages_rv)
rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
rv.adapter = mAdapter
```

**Adapter**

```
class MessageAdapter(messages: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Message>) :
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>(messages) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.message_row, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: Message) {
        holder.message.text = model.message
    }

    // Make a textview variable, and initiate it in the init block, which will be called first after creating the ViewHolder object
     class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val message: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.message_tv)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my app crash with this error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myapplication.Message

I've tried to make a different references to the database, but none of them work. How I may solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the following reference:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Message")
```

And you pass it to the `setQuery()` method:

```
.setQuery(myRef, Message::class.java)
```

Your adapter expects to render on the screen `Message` objects. However, under the `Message` node, there are no such objects but only strings. If you want to map a node into an object of type `Message`, then you should consider using a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- Message
     |
     --- $pushedId
     |     |
     |     --- message: "asd"
     |
     --- $pushedId
           |
           --- message: "asd13"
```

This means that the actual message should exist under a pushed ID.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for help.